# If a then b check in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am performing some data quality checks to identify bad data, I am unable to figure out how I can perform a check-such that the data is accurately mapped based on Value 1 vs Value 2.

I ultimately need to identify all IDs in T1 that have incorrect mapping in T2.I have used the following code but doesn't seem to give desired result. The mapping is not in the database and is a rule based on which the data needs to be entered.
- When value in: Apples,Bananas,Cherries,Pears,Kiwis - then it should be mapped to Fruit
- when value in: Cheese - then Cheese
- when value in: Cashews,Almonds - then Nuts
- when value in: Skittles - then Candy
- when value in: Chocolate - then null

Edit: I have added the desired output.

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.*
FROM t1,t2,t3
WHERE 
    t1.id = t2.id
    AND (
        (t2.value1_id IN (01,04,05,08,09) AND t2.value2_id <> 2)
        OR (t2.value1_id = 02 and t2.value2_id <> 3)
        OR (t2.value1_id IN (03,10) and t2.value2_id <> 1)
        OR (t2.value1_id = 06 AND t2.value2_id <> 4)
        OR (t2.value1_id = 07 AND t2.value_id IS NOT NULL)
    )
```

T1

```
ID     
1    
2    
3 
4 
5   
6
7
```

T2

```
T1.ID Value1_ID Value2_ID    
1       01        2     
1       02        3     
1       03        1    
2       04        2    
2       05        2    
2       02        3    
2       06        4    
2       07             
3       08        2    
3       02        3    
4       09        2    
4       10        1    
5       02        2
5       10        1
6       04        3
6       10        2
7       07        2
```

T3

```
ID   Value1     
01   Apples    
02   Cheese    
03   Cashews    
04   Bananas    
05   Cherries    
06   Skittles    
07   Chocolate    
08   Pears    
09   Kiwis    
10   Almonds
```

T4

```
ID  Value2    
1    Nuts    
2    Fruit    
3    Cheese    
4    Candy
```

Desired Output:

```
T1.ID Value1_ID Value2_ID    
5       02            2
6       04            3    
6       10            2     
7       07            2
```

- T1.ID 5, value1_id 02 is in the desired output as Cheese is mapped to Fruit
- T1.ID 6, value1_id 04 - Bananas is mapped to Cheese
- T1.ID 6, value1_id 10 - Almonds is mapped to Fruit
- T1.ID 7, value1_id 07 - Chocolate is mapped to Fruit when it should be null

Comment: You have given us a query that you say is wrong and some sample data .... How is the query wrong? What is your desired result for your sample data? What does `T3` and `T4` have to do with anything as they aren't mentioned in your query (beyond `T3` being `CROSS JOIN`ed without any filter)? How can we help you when you haven't told us what answer we are trying to get or given any explanation of what your data means.

Comment: How do we identify that *an ID in T1 has incorrect mapping in T2* ?

Comment: Maybe you want a `GROUP BY t1.id`?

Comment: @MT0 : Sorry if my question was not clear, I have added a couple of more scenarios with incorrect mapping and added the desired output, my code definitely is not correct as it is not only returning the rows which have incorrect mapping but seems to be returning all rows from T2.

Comment: @GMB : T2 also has ID from T1.

Comment: @Tomanow : I did try to group by but the code still isnt returning my desired output. I have edited my question to add the desired output.

Comment: Why is that your desired output? Why is `5 02 2` in your output and why is `5 10 1` not in your output? Why are all the rows with `T1.ID` of `6` in your desired output and none of the rows for `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54837302/edit) and give us an **English** explanation of what you are trying to do and **how** we should work out what a correct answer is.

Comment: Especially include in your description how we should get to your desired outcome if we assume that we have no knowledge that an "Apple is a Fruit" or that an "Almond is a Nut" because those relationships are not represented in your data.

Comment: @MT0: That is the challenge I am facing, this is a rule that user needs to enter data based on and the mapping doesn't exist in the database. I am updating my question to add more info.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that - when looking at T2 - it is not easy to tell whether a "mapping" is correct or not.
When creating the test data for T1 and T2, we have used CHARs for VALUE1_IDs, in order to make the subsequent queries a bit more "readable".

**Tables**

```
create table T1( id primary key ) 
as
select 1 from dual union all
select 2 from dual union all
select 3 from dual ;


create table T2 ( id, value1_id, value2_id )
as
select 1, '01', 2 from dual union all
select 1, '02', 3 from dual union all
select 1, '03', 1 from dual union all
select 2, '04', 2 from dual union all
select 2, '05', 2 from dual union all
select 2, '02', 3 from dual union all
select 2, '06', 4 from dual union all
select 2, '07', null  from dual union all
select 3, '08', 2 from dual union all
select 3, '02', 3 from dual union all
select 4, '09', 2 from dual union all
select 4, '10', 1 from dual ;
```

**Refactored query**

```
--
-- find incorrect mappings 
--
select t2.*, 'T1 id not valid' as status
from t2
where t2.id not in ( select id from T1 )
union all
select t2.*, 'value1_id <-> value2_id mapping incorrect '
from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where
    ( t2.value1_id in ('01','04','05','08','09') and t2.value2_id <> 2 )
    or
    ( t2.value1_id = '02' and t2.value2_id <> 3 )
    or
    ( t2.value1_id in ('03','10') and t2.value2_id <> 1 )
    or
    ( t2.value1_id = '06' and t2.value2_id <> 4 )
    or
    ( t2.value1_id = '07' and t2.value2_id is null )
;

-- result
ID  VALUE1_ID  VALUE2_ID  STATUS                                      
4   10         1          T1 id not valid                             
4   09         2          T1 id not valid                             
2   07         NULL       value1_id <-> value2_id mapping incorrect
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d2f0e941cd4c0e3f5596494744156ed1)

**ALTERNATIVE**

Another possibility may be: create a table, containing all valid mappings, in "human readable" form, and use it to validate the mappings stored in T2.  However, use whatever approach you are more comfortable with - as long as you get the correct results.  Example (tested w/ Oracle 12c, 18c)

```
-- in addition to tables T1, T2, T3, and T4: table with correct mappings
create table map( category, product )
as
select 'Fruit', 'Apples' from dual union all
select 'Cheese', 'Cheese' from dual union all
select 'Nuts', 'Cashews' from dual union all
select 'Fruit', 'Bananas' from dual union all
select 'Fruit', 'Cherries' from dual union all
select 'Candy', 'Skittles' from dual union all
select 'Candy', 'Chocolate' from dual union all
select 'Fruit', 'Pears' from dual union all
select 'Fruit', 'Kiwis' from dual union all
select 'Nuts', 'Almonds' from dual;

-- make sure that the entries in the MAP table tie in with T3 and T4
alter table map 
add (
  constraint m_pk primary key ( category, product )
, constraint m_category_fk foreign key ( category ) references T4 ( value2 )
, constraint m_product_fk foreign key ( product ) references T3 ( value1 )
) ;
```

**Find incorrect mappings**

```
-- T2 rows containing incorrect (invalid) mappings
--   -> all rows MINUS the correct ones
select T2.id, T2.value1_id, T2.value2_id
from T2
minus (
  select T2.id, T2.value1_id, T2.value2_id
  from T2
    join (
  --
    select T4.id categoryid, T3.id productid, M.category, M.product
    from T4
      join map M on T4.value2 = M.category
      join T3    on T3.value1 = M.product
  --
  ) C -- correct mappings
    on 
      C.productid = T2.value1_id
  and C.categoryid = T2.value2_id
) ;

-- result
ID  VALUE1_ID  VALUE2_ID  
2   07         NULL
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=62a1a37268f3f044251e9305d22d5cef)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you create a table to represent the one-to-many relationship between `T4`  and `T3`. This would represent a first step towards fixing your design, while providing a simple way to solve your current question.

Here is a `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` order that initializes such a table with your sample data :

```
create table cat AS
SELECT 1 t3_id, 2 t4_id FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, NULL FROM DUAL
;
```

With this table in place, indentifiying records incorrectly mapped is as simple as :

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM t2
WHERE t2.Value2_ID IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM cat WHERE cat.t3_id = t2.Value1_ID AND cat.t4_id = t2.Value2_ID
)
```

This **[DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d76d35fa2710b5d835383ca97d591b97)** with your sample data yields :

```
T1_ID | VALUE1_ID | VALUE2_ID
----: | --------: | --------:
    5 |         2 |         2
    6 |         4 |         3
    6 |        10 |         2
    7 |         7 |         2
```

---

Hint to further improve your design : you have a one-to-many relationship between `T4` (families of aliments) and `T3` (aliments). The classic way to represent this is to add a column in the child table (`T3`) that references the parent table.

Comment: I have updated my question to add more details, the mapping is not in the database and unfortunately, I cannot create a table at this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create a table with the mappings from fruit to categories and you know that the values are static then just include the mappings into your query using a nested sub-query or a sub-query factoring clause:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
create table T2 ( id, value1_id, value2_id ) as
select 1, '01', 2 from dual union all
select 1, '02', 3 from dual union all
select 1, '03', 1 from dual union all
select 2, '04', 2 from dual union all
select 2, '05', 2 from dual union all
select 2, '02', 3 from dual union all
select 2, '06', 4 from dual union all
select 2, '07', null  from dual union all
select 3, '08', 2 from dual union all
select 3, '02', 3 from dual union all
select 4, '09', 2 from dual union all
select 4, '10', 1 from dual union all
select 5, '02', 2 from dual union all
select 5, '10', 1 from dual union all
select 6, '04', 3 from dual union all
select 6, '10', 2 from dual union all
select 7, '07', 2 from dual;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH mappings ( name, category ) AS (
  SELECT '01', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '02', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '03', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '04', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '05', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '06', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '07', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '08', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '09', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '10', 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   T2 t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   mappings m
  WHERE  t.value1_id = m.name
  AND    (  t.value2_id = m.category
         OR ( t.value2_id IS NULL AND m.category IS NULL ) )
);
```

**Results**:

```
ID | VALUE1_ID | VALUE2_ID
-: | :-------- | --------:
 5 | 02        |         2
 6 | 04        |         3
 6 | 10        |         2
 7 | 07        |         2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4310465be5baa0b07cc36eb3f7189890)*